# Creating a shared, asynchronous, cancellable Observable with a custom function in RxPy

Tags: python

This is an exercise in using ReactiveX in Python. I want to create an Observable in [RxPy](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxPY) with the following characteristics:

- Emits items through a custom function
- Runs asynchronously
- Sets up resources upon start and it cleans up at the end
- Runs a loop indefinitely (until cancelled)
- Can be cancelled
- Shared among observers

Kind of like wrapping HTTP streaming data with an Observable.

Thinking that it would work like RxJs, I started defining a straightforward function and using the [create](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/create.html) operator. It got hairy very quick and I ended up doing a lot of asyncio stuff that I wasn't expecting to do.

How does this code look and how could I improve it (particularly `observable_fn`)?

You can run it with Python 3.5 and stop it with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. I'm working on a Mac.

```
import asyncio
from rx import Observer, Observable
from rx.core import Scheduler

def observable_fn(observer):
    _task = None

    # Customize this
    def _setup():
        print('Observable setup')

    # Customize this
    def _teardown():
        print('Observable teardown')
        if _task:
            _task.cancel()
        observer.on_completed()

    # Customize this
    async def _loop():
        counter = 0

        while True:
            await asyncio.sleep(2) # Simulating long-running task
            counter += 1
            observer.on_next(counter)

    # Don't touch this
    async def _run_loop():
        try:
            await _loop()
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            print('Observable cancelled')
        finally:
            _teardown()

    # Don't touch this
    _setup()
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    _task = loop.create_task(_run_loop())

print('CREATING OBSERVABLE')
observable = Observable.create(observable_fn).observe_on(Scheduler.event_loop).share()

print('CREATING OBSERVERS')
observer1 = observable.subscribe(lambda x: print('O1: {0}'.format(x)))
observer2 = observable.subscribe(lambda x: print('O2: {0}'.format(x)))
observer3 = observable.subscribe(lambda x: print('O3: {0}'.format(x)))

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
try:
    print('STARTING LOOP')
    loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pending_tasks = asyncio.Task.all_tasks()
    for task in pending_tasks:
        task.cancel()

    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*pending_tasks))
    loop.close()

print('THE END')
```

Comment: Did you end up using the code this way?

I want to implement something similar and am having doubts about the event loop. You seem to ask for one as part of your observable function, while I was thinking it might be better to have a wrapper function that gets the event loop as an argument from the "main" function.

Comment: I didn’t. This was a learning exercise and I haven’t used the code in any practical application. I’ll revisit this question to consider your suggestion. Thank you